# UIButton above UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, addsubview

I have a tableView in a UIViewController. My tableView is NOT an IBOutlet.

The UIViewController has a navigation bar due to being pushed from another view.

I want to add a UIButton above the tableview, but buttons/views do not appear above the tableview even if I add them in storyboard or use the "bringSubviewToFront" method.

I noticed that buttons/vews do appear behind the navigation bar when translucent, but that of course is not where I want them.

None of these codes have worked:

```
[self.view addSubview:btnSend];// add Send btn
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnSend];// bring Send btn to Front
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:btnSend];
[self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:btnSend];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the table view's header?

Comment: Yes. I have a header already made and do not want my button to show in the header.

Comment: How and where do you setup your table and how and where do you set up your button?

Comment: TableView in ViewDidLoad : self.tblView = [[UITableView alloc] init]...[self.view addSubview:self.tblView];

Button initialized in ViewDidLoad but added via [self.view addSubview:button] in a targeted method. I've checked if the method is reached by NSLog.

Comment: Have you checked the frame rect? You could check this in function "- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews" - if the rect value is not same as expected one then you can reposition the UI element here.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to set the `edgesForExtendedLayout` so that the top is not included

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeLeft | UIRectEdgeBottom | UIRectEdgeRight;
```

Comment: didn't change anything.